# How can I expand collapsed text with an anchor tag in the URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a page that uses the code below to expand and collapse paragraphs of text. Now, I need to setup anchor tags so that a link, e.g. www.website.com/page#section1, will automatically expand the text.

Seems like I could add location.hash to the current function, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Thanks in advance!

```
<a name="section1"><h3><span id="toggleControlS2" onClick="toggleS2();">Section 1</span></h3></a>

<p id="hiddenTextBlockS2">Paragraph of text</p>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var toggleControlS2=document.getElementById("toggleControlS2");
var hiddenTextBlockS2=document.getElementById("hiddenTextBlockS2");

function toggleS2()
{
    if(hiddenTextBlockS2.style.display=="block")
    {
        hiddenTextBlockS2.style.display="none";
        toggleControlS2.innerHTML="Section 1 +";
    }
    else if(hiddenTextBlockS2.style.display=="none")
    {
        hiddenTextBlockS2.style.display="block";
        toggleControlS2.innerHTML="Section 1 -";
    }
}

hiddenTextBlockS2.style.display="none";
toggleControlS2.style.cursor="pointer";
</script>
```

Comment: Although there are cleaner ways, the quickest way to build on what you have would be to 1) add `return false;` to the end of your `toggleS2()` function, and then 2) your anchor would look like `<a href="#" onclick="return toggleS2();">Toggle</a>`. IMO it would be worth studying "unobtrusive JavaScript," which would involve removing your inline click events and binding the events in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Add it below

What is happening here is that once the page loads, we check the location hash to see if it matches "#section1". If it does, we execute the same logic as clicking on the #toggleControlS2 span.

e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var toggleControlS2=document.getElementById("toggleControlS2");
var hiddenTextBlockS2=document.getElementById("hiddenTextBlockS2");

function toggleS2()
{
    if(hiddenTextBlockS2.style.display=="block")
    {
        hiddenTextBlockS2.style.display="none";
        toggleControlS2.innerHTML="Accepted (peer-reviewed) Version +";
    }
    else if(hiddenTextBlockS2.style.display=="none")
    {
        hiddenTextBlockS2.style.display="block";
        toggleControlS2.innerHTML="Accepted (peer-reviewed) Version -";
    }
}

hiddenTextBlockS2.style.display="none";
toggleControlS2.style.cursor="pointer";

if(location.hash === "#section1"){
  toggleS2();
}
</script>
```